# Arranging Labels

Tags: java, layout, swt

How can I arrange `Label`s on a canvas from its top left down and so on?
and if you can show me how to do that in a loop.

I tried to use `GridData`, but I don't think I understand it that much.

```
GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.LEFT);
Label lbl = new Label(canvas, SWT.LEFT);
lbl.setText("A: ");
lbl.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
lbl.setLayoutData(gd);
Label lbl2 = new Label(c,SWT.TOP);
lbl.setText("B: ");
lbl.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
lbl2.setLayoutData(gd);
```

Comment: What should the result look like? If you plan to use `GridLayout`, how many columns do you want?

Comment: I want it to look like a column of labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want one column, use `RowLayout` with `SWT.VERTICAL`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Label " + i);
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @user3061943 BTW: Why do you use a `Canvas`?

Answer (score 0):

SWT.LEFT and SWT.TOP
 first of all, shouldn't that be the same or?
 second
 with array
 just loop trough the array and for each value create a label
 size/position is just (in %) 100/TOTAL * KEY
(if KEY starts at 0 and goes to the highest)